# Fibre products and induced short exact sequences in abelian categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Assume we have an abelian category which has fibre products. Let $f:X\to Z$ and $g:Y\to Z$ be two morphisms and let $(W,p,q)$ be their fibre product with $p:W\to X$, $q:W\to Y$. If the category is a module category over some ring and $f$ is an epimorphism, then we get an induced short exact sequence $0\to K\to W\to Y\to 0$, where $K$ is the kernel of $f$. My question is if this is true in arbitrary abelian categories with fibre products. I am able to show that the kernel of $q$ is isomorphic to the kernel of $f$, so it would suffice to show that $q$ is an epimorphism if $f$ is an epimorphism. But I don't know how to manage that.

If the category is small, then I know that it is equivalent to some module category. So I am searching for a completely arrow-theoretic proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every abelian category has fiber products. In fact, fiber products can always be constructed via equalizers and products, and equalizers in $\mathsf{Ab}$-categories may be reduced to kernels.

Your question is why epimorphisms in abelian categories are stable under pullback. You can find the proof in Mac Lane's *CWM*, Chapter VIII, Prop. 4.2.

By the way, you can also assumethat your abelian category is small (consider the closure of $X,Y,\dotsc,f,g,\dotsc$ under direct sums, kernels and cokernels) and then use the embedding theorem of Freyd-Mitchell.